# Interface newbie trying to use VB.NET Interfaces and classes to create a Plugin system

Tags: vb.net, plugins, interface

I am sorry if this question seems a desperately dummy question to you but I have some trouble understanding how to implement an interface in a separate dll project, willing to create a plugin system for an application of mine.

Reading some stuff out there, I created an IPlugin interface, which (I guess) is fine, using

```
Public Interface IPlugin
    Sub DoSomething()
    Function Description() As String

End Interface

Public Class ImplementationClass
    Implements IPlugin

    Public Sub DoSomething() Implements IPlugin.DoSomething
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Function Description() As String Implements IPlugin.Description
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, I created a separate project containing the sample plugin, supposed to be one of the "addons", which looks like

```
Public Class MyPlugin : Implements .......... (normally IPlugin, right?)
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!")
    End Sub

    Public Function Description() As String
        Return "This is my plugin"
    End Function

End Class
```

Now, trying to add the `Implements IPlugin` to the MyPlugin class just does not work since it cannot find the IPlugin interface anywhere (reference...)

I must be doing something really stupid, but I just have absolutely no clue as to what I'm doing wrong even after browsing the internet for hours...

Could someone help a poor 71-years-old-French frog to understand where he miserably fails :-)

Thx and stay healthy!

Philippe

Comment: You will need to add an ````Inherits SomeDLL```` in order to reference the name ````IPlugin```` directly.  Alternatively, you could  ````Implements SomeDLL.IPlugin```` and use the full path to the ````IPlugin```` -- EDIT: since I didn't see the namespace for where the IPlugin is at, I just used SomeDLL as a variable for what you'd use when you know the namespace.

Comment: The basic pattern is to have a standalone class library that defines `IPlugin`. Then both the plugin host program and the actual plugin library can reference the `IPlugin` assembly (i.e. Project Menu->Add Reference->IPlugin.dll).

Comment: Hi, Thx to both of you I got the interface properly referenced (I guess). However, selecting and loading the dll with a TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance of the assembly type returns nothing while supposed to help me use the method and the function...Any idea? Thanks again...Philippe

Comment: The basic approach looks right.  You might want to make a new question for your last comment, I think it's different enough from this question to merit it.  I can't tell what's going wrong just from your description.

Comment: Finally got it to work using a different scenario. Thx to both of you guys!